# Visa-free countries

Tags: usa

I have a refugee travel document issued by the USA. What countries are visa-free for me, and what countries allow me to get a visa on my refugee travel document? I got approved for my asylum case but I don't have a green card yet. I will apply for it next April.

Thank you.

Comment: This post seems to be very related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46413/travelling-through-the-schengen-area-with-a-refugee-travel-document-issued-by-th