# Visit to Germany with refugee travel documents from Australia?

Tags: schengen, germany, refugees

I want to visit Germany for 2 weeks with my 2 kids and wife. We have an Australian convention travel document, except our little daughter, who has an Australian passport. Do we need a visa to enter Germany?

Comment: @dda You're awesome with your quick edits! Wish to see you become a mod here someday.

Comment: @HankyPanky Christmas/New Year's holidays + OCD = win :-)

Comment: Not a definite answer, but in https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/46414/67108 it says that Germany doesn't require a visa from people with a Travel Document from the US. One might surmise that it is the same for Australia, but but but, this would need to be confirmed...

Answer (score 1):

You and your family with travel document valid for at least 4 months can enter visa free for 90 days

> Holders of UN Travel documents, issued by the Australian Government
>   according to the UN Conventions for refugees (Convention of 28 July
>   1951) and stateless persons (Convention of 28 September 1954),
>   mentioned on the front page, can enter Germany without a visa for an
>   intended stay of up to 90 days, as long as at the time of entry into
>   Germany their travel document is still valid for at least 4 months and
>   they do not engage in any type of gainful employment.

Your daughter with an Australian passport can also enter visa free for 90 days.

> Australian citizens do not need a visa for the Schengen area, which
>   includes Germany, for an intended stay of up to 90 days in a 180 day
>   period as long as
>
> - their passports are valid for at least 3 months beyond the intended length of stay in the Schengen zone and they do not engage in any type
>     of gainful employment

[German mission to Australia](http://www.australien.diplo.de/Vertretung/australien/en/03/Visa/Schengenvisa/Schengenvisa.html)

Answer (score -2):

> Australian citizens do not need to apply for a visa to visit the Schengen countries for a maximum of 90 days in any 180-day period. The 90 days can be used either for one long stay or several shorter stays.
>
> > **Germany tourist visa is not required for citizens of Australia for a stay up to 90 days.**

- https://germany.visahq.com.au/

Comment: This is the answer for the daughter with Australian citizenship, but not for the other three people.

Comment: Convention travel document is for refugees, not citizens...