# What countries in the Schengen area accept US travel document (form I-571)

Tags: visas, usa, schengen, refugees

I'm planning a trip to Europe this summer (Italy, Spain and Portugal) and will be using my travel document (Form I-571) that I have based on asylum from Syria. I had a visa appointment at the Spanish consulate today and was not able to submit the application as the officer mentioned that Spain does not recognize refugee/asylee travel documents.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Re-entry_Permit) wikipedia page mentions that Spain accepts U.S. travel documents, however, I've read other sources that site the opposite such as [this thread](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46413/travelling-through-the-schengen-area-with-a-refugee-travel-document-issued-by-th). Do you know which countries accept a travel document (with a Schengen visa) in 2019? I'd appreciate if you can include an official website, I'm having a hard time finding any.

Comment: The [Travel.SE] thread you link to says that someone with an I-571 needs a visa to visit Spain.  But you report that you've been told that you *cannot get* a visa for Spain with that document.  I think that is terribly wrong (not least because the document is issued under the 1967 protocol of the 1951 refugee convention, and both Spain and the US have signed and ratified the protocol), and that both Wikipedia and the answers to the question you link to are correct.  I think the question you *ought* to be asking is "how can I get the Spanish consulate to process my visa application?"

Comment: It's not the first time I've heard of Spain refusing to accept a US refugee travel document, but it has been quite a while and I don't have a source handy. As I recall, their sticking point was that the US signed the 1967 protocol but not the original 1951 convention. Have you thought about visiting Germany?

Comment: It seems like Germany is among a few countries that allow the U.S. travel document holder to travel visa free. However, the main reason I'm going to Spain is to attend a friend's wedding, would probably be inconvenient to ask him to move it to Germany haha. Any idea if I could travel through Spain if I get the Schengen visa from another European country or would that be illegal?

Comment: You could probably manage it if you didn't say anything to the German immigration authorities, and don't fly on Ryanair. I think the risk of having a problem is fairly low, as I said in the other post, but I suppose it is not technically legal, and I can't tell you what your tolerance for risk is.

Comment: Update: I applied to the Schengen visa through France and I received the visa today. The visa allows me entry to the Schengen states except Spain, Portugal, Iceland, Poland and Malta which apparently are the countries that do not recognize the U.S. travel document.

Comment: @AdnanBaleh could you turn that into an answer, please?

Comment: @MarkMayoSupportsMonica excuse my ignorance, how do I turn a comment into an answer?

Comment: @AdnanBaleh in the answer box, expand on it and write it as an answer to your question in the "Your answer" box below.  Then either delete your comment, or flag it as no longer needed and we can come along and clean it up. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to Adnan:

> Update: I applied to the Schengen visa through France and I received the visa today. The visa allows me entry to the Schengen states except Spain, Portugal, Iceland, Poland and Malta which apparently are the countries that do not recognize the U.S. travel document.

If someone knows a better source for this information, please edit this answer in the future.

Comment: A subsequent question and answer on this same topic (different countries, but same issue) is located [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/177400/visiting-schengen-countries-with-us-refuge-travel-document-form-i-571-without).