# Entering Italy with Australian travel document

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen-visas

I enter Germany with Australian travel document for refugees.
Can I take another flight to Italy and move freely in schengen area?

Comment: Related: [Travelling through the Schengen area with a Refugee Travel Document issued by the USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/46413/3221)